# sed: if line does not contain lower-case, add a blank line above and below

Tags: sed

There are a number of questions here about sed to find lines that don't contain a string, but all of them seem to be about then deleting those lines. I want to keep mine, with a blank line added above and below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try doing this :

```
$ sed '/[[:lower:]]/!{a
i
}' file.txt
```

Comment: This leaves me with only the lines that don't have lower-case letters. Dropping the -n fixes that, but then the lines without lower-case letters are duplicated. I'll use the one-liner to remove duplicate lines until I figure out how to fix that.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an `awk` solution:

```
awk '!/[[:lower:]]/ {$0=RS$0RS}1' file
```

If line does not have any `lower` characters, add Record Selector (newline) before and after line, then print.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/[[:lower:]]/b;x;p;x;G' file
```